# How to view all WiFi networks around me

Tags: wireless

How can I view all the available wifi networks around me?

Comment: Which difficulties have you faced that u need to asked this question? You did not even try to see from network manager. Just click on network-indicator and see wifi is enabled or not.If not then enable, you can see  all the available wifi. OR if you already know this and other issue, then edit your question.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). What are you actually trying to achieve? Maybe connect to one of them?

Answer (score 1):

At top right corner of your system you can see a signal symbol. Click on that and tick the Enable Wi-Fi.It will show all available Wi-Fi networks.

Comment: Actually it is showing only the one which i was connected at the time of installation

Comment: Try this open a terminal using ctrl+Alt+t and enter the below command                                                                                                                                         sudo iwlist scan

Answer (score 1):

I've seen many occasions where, for some reason, NetworkManager's GUI doesn't show all the available networks.  In fact at times it doesn't even list Wireless as a choice.  On those occasions I use the cli option to scan:

```
$ nmcli -f in-use,ssid,bssid,signal,bars  dev wifi

*  SSID               BSSID              SIGNAL  BARS 
   Apollo III (TWC)   xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  100     ▂▄▆█ 
   Chromecast8481     xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  100     ▂▄▆█ 
   TWCWiFi-Passpoint  xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  90      ▂▄▆█ 
   Apollo III (1)     xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  90      ▂▄▆█ 
   CableWiFi          xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  87      ▂▄▆█ 
   TWCWiFi            xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  87      ▂▄▆█ 
*  Apollo III (1)     xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  70      ▂▄▆_ 
   ZJG8Q              xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  47      ▂▄__
```

*For security reason I X'ed out the mac addresses.*

If I have connected to the network before I can use this cli to connect again:

```
$ nmcli c up "Apollo III (1)"
```

If I'm connecting for the first time I'll use this command:

```
$ nmcli d wifi connect "Apollo III (1)"
```

A GUI prompt will come up with the option to type in the code works the terminal screen will respond with `successful activation` and I'll be connected.

I also tested to verified that the elevated `sudo` command isn't required for any of the commands above.